# Автоматически поставить ссылку

Tags: php, html

У меня есть список новостей. Я хочу, чтобы ссылка в тексте новости автоматически обозначалась между тегами . Каким образом это можно сделать на php? Возожно через preg_match или что-то в таком роде

Comment: Обозначалась чем? Уточните, пожалуйста, вопрос.

Comment: URL в тексте делался ссылкой <a>

Comment: И вопрос: при чём тут javascript?

Comment: Вдруг можно через него обозначить...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью регулярных выражений и функции `preg_replace()`, например, [этого](http://urlregex.com/):

```
$text = "http://urlregex.com";
$pattern = "%^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}|(?:(?:[a-z\d\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]+-?)*[a-z\d\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\d\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]+-?)*[a-z\d\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]+)*(?:\.[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,6}))(?::\d+)?(?:[^\s]*)?$%iu";
$replacement = "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Что значит автоматически? Где это нужно сделать? Вы обозначили PHP, JavaScript и html. В любом случае  ссылка обозначается как:

```
<a href"URL">text</a>
```

Comment: В тексте пользователь написал ссылку. А я хочу, чтобы это была рабочая ссылка, а не просто текст

Comment: Вы будете сохранять эту ссылку в БД? Если да, то выводя на экран просто делаете это ссылкой.

Comment: Но её надо выделить из общего текста

Comment: Каким образом выделить? Нужно размер поменять или что? Отображаться в любом случае будет как текст синего цвета и подчеркнутый.

Comment: Нужно автоматически с помощью php из одной большой строки или текста искать любое слово, начинающееся на http:// или https:// его ЭТИМ же urlом, но теперь как ссылку <a>

Comment: Вполне возможно, что можно воспользоваться и Jaascript, но я лично знаю что в php есить функция strpos:http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php